# Android: upload video on YouTube with filename not date

Tags: android, youtube, upload, title

YouTube put date instead filename in title, I can't find option where change that,coz if many videos very uncomfy rename manually

Try find option & fail...
Some users says on they Android YouTube use filename not date of upload,but I don't change that option,coz I dunno where it is